# Generate PDF containing multiple SVG barcodes

Tags: python, svg, python-barcode

I am trying to generate a PDF containing all the barcodes in SVG format. Here is the code I've written so far.

```
from code128 import Code128
import csv
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Group, Drawing
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter

# Scale of SVG images
SVG_SCALE = 10

# Read the CSV file
with open('products.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    products = [(row['code'], row['name']) for row in reader]

# Generate barcodes for each product and add to drawing
drawing = Drawing(width=letter[0], height=letter[1])
x, y = 50, 50
for product_code, product_name in products:
    # Generate SVG barcode using code128 library
    ean = Code128(product_code)
    barcode_svg = ean.svg(scale=SVG_SCALE)

    # Create a reportlab group for the barcode and set its transform
    barcode_group = Group()
    barcode_group.transform = (SVG_SCALE, 0, 0, SVG_SCALE, x, y)
    barcode_group.add(barcode_svg)
    drawing.add(barcode_group)

    # Add product name below barcode
    drawing.addString(x + (barcode_svg.width * SVG_SCALE) / 2, y - 10, product_name, fontSize=10, textAnchor="middle")

    # Move cursor to the next barcode position
    y += 75
    if y > 750:
        y = 50
        x += 200

# Render drawing as PDF
renderPDF.drawToFile(drawing, "barcodes.pdf", "Barcode Sheet")
```

The error I get is `ImportError: cannot import name 'Code128' from 'code128'`

I can't find another way to achieve what I'm after. Can someone please help me fix the imports/code or another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly install `python_barcode` package. Don't get confused with `barcode` package. barcode package must be un-installed if already isntalled.

```
from barcode.codex import Code128
from barcode.writer import SVGWriter
import csv
import os

BARCODE_SCALE = 3

if not os.path.exists('gen_svg'):
    os.makedirs('gen_svg')


def generate_barcode_svg(code):
    barcode_svg = Code128(code, writer=SVGWriter())
    return barcode_svg.render()


with open('products.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        svg_name = row['code']
        product_string = row['code'] + ' : ' + row['name']
        barcode_svg = generate_barcode_svg(product_string)
        with open(f'gen_svg/{svg_name}.svg', 'w') as f:
            f.write(barcode_svg.decode('utf-8'))
```